# create a StreamSource with getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceStream(

Tags: junit, mocking, junit4, easymock, powermock

I post this question and I got some explanations but I couldn't solve the problem. Now since event I have a better understanding I'm going to post this again in a new angle.

I have following lines in my node.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

        /*
         * Associate the schema factory with the resource resolver, which is
         * responsible for resolving the imported XSD's
         */
        factory.setResourceResolver(new ResourceResolver());

        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaName));
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
```

I think I have two options. Either to mock

```
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaName));
```

or

```
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

I have been pulling my hair for two day to do the first one. I tried as follows

```
expectNew(StreamSource.class, InputStream.class).andReturn(mockSource);
```

and

```
expectNew(StreamSource.class, anyObject(InputStream.class)).andReturn(mockSource);
```

But didn't work.

Now I'm trying to mock the second line

```
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

This one also not quite clear to me. Do I need to mock a factory like

```
SchemaFactory mockFactory = EasyMock.createMock(SchemaFactory.class);
```

or since factory is created using newInstance static method call is it a different way?

Appreciate any help on this problem.

**Adding later**

I got some lead with the situation. I have expectNew as follows.

```
expectNew(StreamSource.class, InputStream.class).andReturn(mockStreamSource);
```

When I run powermocks throws a error saying.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected constructor call javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(null):
    javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(class java.io.InputStream): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

The reason is as I think getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceStream("..") return null anyway. So powermock didn't find it euqal to the initialization I describe by expectNew. How to say expect a null inputstream as parameter. I tried using just null. didn't work.

```
expectNew(StreamSource.class, null).andReturn(mockStreamSource);
```

Comment: Would your code be more testable if you passed in a `StreamSource`, rather than constructing it within the method?

Comment: @Joe Yes but change the code it bit hard now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using easymock:

Extract the creation of the factory to a protected method.

```
protected SchemaFactory createSchemaFactory(){
  return SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
}
```

In your test, instead of test the SUT itself create a partially mocked version of your SUT, mocking only the new method where the static invocation is done, and test it. [Partial mocks using easymock](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IMockBuilder.html).

Comment: Yes this works. But still I need to make this work with the current code.

Comment: Do you mean you have to test the method but you can't refactor? That's a point to know.

Comment: yes due to some curcumstances I cannot. The effort is to get the coverage up.